# In Pandas frame make column entry that is a list break up its items so that they are listed vertical individually

Tags: python, pandas

I've been working on this for hours trying to figure out how to make this json

```js
{
    "method": "STATIC",
    "type": "IEEE_8023AD",
    "dns_search_domains": [
        "lab.local1",
        "lab.local2",
        "lab.local3"
    ],
    "dns_servers": [
        "11.12.200.1",
        "11.12.200.2",
        "11.12.200.3"
    ]
}
```

convert to this output in pandas

```
       method         type  dns_search_domains    dns_servers
0      STATIC  IEEE_8023AD          lab.local1    11.12.200.1
                                    lab.local2    11.12.200.2
                                    lab.local3    11.12.200.3
```

Instead the best I can come up with is this.
I keep getting this list format under columns dns_search_domains and dns_servers.

```
   method         type                 dns_search_domains                                 dns_servers
0  STATIC  IEEE_8023AD  [lab.local1, lab.local2, lab.local3]  [11.12.200.1, 11.12.200.2, 11.12.200.3]
```

Looks like the list format is not allowing me to break the items up individually so they can output vertical under their column.

Here is the basic code.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with open ('network_conf_get.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)

data = json_normalize(d)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 0)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None) 
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)
print(pd.DataFrame(data))
```

Comment: If using pandas 0.25+ ,yo ucan use `explode` on the columns `dns_search_domains` & `dns_servers`

Comment: Forgive my manners. I forgot to say any help would be greatly appreciated please.

Comment: `pd.concat([df[['method', 'type', 'dns_search_domains']].explode('dns_search_domains'), df.dns_servers.explode()], axis=1)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass to dataframe constructor the `set_index`

```
pd.DataFrame(d).set_index(['method','type'])
Out[229]: 
                   dns_search_domains  dns_servers
method type                                       
STATIC IEEE_8023AD         lab.local1  11.12.200.1
       IEEE_8023AD         lab.local2  11.12.200.2
       IEEE_8023AD         lab.local3  11.12.200.3
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I added another column containing this emtpy array "floating_ip_ranges": [] but now get this error ValueError: arrays must all be same length :(.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks set_index did help.

Unfortunately, if I decide to add another column of data with a list of a different length compared to columns to "dns_search_domains" and "dns_servers" then I get this error

```
ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

At this point I've opted to just build out each column manually with pd.Series() and then concatenate them with pd.concat(). Unless anyone has any other suggestions thank you for the help friends!!